# How to Iterate through all the rows of Excel sheet in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, excel, robotframework

How to iterate of all the rows of the Excel sheet. ?

below is my code

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
${path_excel}   C:\\User\\Test.xlsx



*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Test the ExcelData

*** Keywords ***


Test the ExcelData
    ${my_data_as_list}=    Create List
    #open the Excel  ${path_excel}
    open excel document   filename=${path_excel}  doc_id=Sheet2
    
    FOR   ${i}   IN  20
      ${my_data}=  Read Excel Cell  row_num=${i}  col_num=1
       Log to Console  ${my_data}
      Append To List    ${my_data_as_list}      ${my_data}

    Log to Console   ${my_data_as_list}
    END
```

it's printing nothing

```
PS C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\RobotFramework\Automation> robot .\ExcelExtract.robot
==============================================================================
ExcelExtract
==============================================================================
Test1                                                                 None
[None]
Test1                                                                 | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExcelExtract                                                          | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\RobotFramework\Automation\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\RobotFramework\Automation\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\RobotFramework\Automation\report.html
```

I tried all the possible ways searched online, and was also unable to get the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change
`FOR   ${i}   IN  20`
to
`FOR   ${i}   IN RANGE    1    20`

Comment: Thank you, it worked one more thing do you know how to get the row count ??

Comment: Consider that you want to get row count of column A. 
    ${col_data}=    Read Excel Column    col_num=1    
     ${row_num}=    evaluate    len(${col_data})
* Sorry I have no idea how to linebreak in comment.